# Convert ASCII TO UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii

How to convert ASCII encoding to UTF8 in PHP

Answer (score 55):

ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so if a document is ASCII then it is already UTF-8.

Comment: Word of caution, if the ASCII is "extended" ascii, then you may encounter issues.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII

Answer (score 33):

If you know for sure that your current encoding is pure ASCII, then you don't have to do anything because ASCII is already a valid UTF-8.

But if you still want to convert, just to be sure that its UTF-8, then you can use iconv

```
$string = iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $string);
```

The IGNORE will discard any invalid characters just in case some were not valid ASCII.

Comment: I’ve always understood “IGNORE” to be automatically/implicitly wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Use **mb_convert_encoding** to convert an ASCII to UTF-8. More info [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

```
$string = "chárêctërs";
print(mb_detect_encoding ($string));

$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8");
print(mb_detect_encoding ($string));
```

Comment: Only one solution which working for me, thanks a lot for this!

Comment: This answer is basically wrong. [mb_detect_encoding ()](https://php.net/mb_detect_encoding) is both poorly named and poorly documented. All it does is looping through a system-dependent and typically short list of encodings (in my system, only `ASCII` and `UTF-8`) and returning the first one where your all bytes have something assigned. Detecting text encoding programmatically in a reliable way is as hard as detecting whether a picture has a cat.

Answer (score 5):

"ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so..." - so UTF-8 is a **set**? :)

In other words: any string build with `code points` from x00 to x7F has indistinguishable **representations** (byte sequences) in ASCII and UTF-8. Converting such string is pointless.

Comment: Key phrase here is the "code points from x00 to x7F".  If your "ASCII" has code points from x10 to xFF, then you need to do more work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `utf8_encode()`

Man page can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Also read this article from Joel on Software. It provides an excellent explanation if what Unicode is and how it works. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: utf8_encode was designed to encode latin-1 into utf-8. Only for latin-1 (which is ISO-8859-1).

Comment: This answer is wrong. As per docs, "Encodes an **ISO-8859-1** string to UTF-8". ISO-8859-1 is not ASCII just like Spanish is not Latin.