# how to convert an ASCII encoded string to UTF8 in php?

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii

I tried to do:
file_put_contents ( $file_name, utf8_encode($data) ) ;
But when i check the file encoding from the shell with the linux command: 'file file_name'
I get: 'file_name:  ASCII text'

Does it mean that the utf8_encoding didn't worked? if so, what is the right way to convert from ASCII to UTF8

Answer (score 1):

If your string doesn't contain any non-ASCII characters, then you likely won't see differences, since UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII. Try writing, for example, the text "1000 さくら" and see what happens.

Comment: +1, that, too. ASCII-only characters in UTF-8 are detected as ASCII by `file` tool.

Comment: my string contain Japanese characters

Answer (score 1):

> Please note that utf8_encode only converts a string encoded in
>   ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. A more appropriate name for it would be
>   "iso88591_to_utf8". If your text is not encoded in  ISO-8859-1, you do
>   not need this function. If your text is already in UTF-8, you do not
>   need this function. In fact, applying this function to text that is
>   not encoded in ISO-8859-1 will most likely simply garble that text.
>
> If you need to convert text from any encoding to any other encoding,
>   look at iconv() instead.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

> ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so if a document is ASCII then it is already UTF-8

Found at: [Convert ASCII TO UTF-8 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983989/convert-ascii-to-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: my string contain Japanese characters

Comment: Use iconv then. There is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII');
file_put_contents ( $file_name, $data );
```

or use this to change file encoding:

```
$fd = fopen($file, 'r');
stream_filter_append($fd, 'convert.iconv.UTF-8/ASCII');
stream_copy_to_stream($fd, fopen($output, 'w'));
```

Reference: [How to write file in UTF-8 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format)