# how to replace special chars in php

Tags: php, cakephp, special-characters, chars, before-save

I have a code that i have to replace few special chars:
code below:

```
#include <iostream>\012#include <stdio.h>\012#include <stdlib.h>\012#include <limits>\012#include <string.h>\012using namespace std;\012\012void inclean(){\012\011std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\\n');\012}\012\012void die(string e){\012\011//cout << e;\012\011exit(1);\012}\012\012typedef struct {\012\011bool zajente;\012\011int rozmiar;\012} pudelko;\012\012int main() {\012\011int i = 12;\012setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);\012\011setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);\012\011int a;\012\011int lamount=0;\012\011cin >> a;\012\011if(!(a>=1&&a<=1000000)){die("Liczba mo\277e wynosi\346 od 1 do 1000000(10^6)");}\012\011pudelko  *pudelka=new pudelko[a];\012\011memset (pudelka,0,a*sizeof(pudelko));\012\011string b;\012\011inclean();\012\011getline(cin,b);\012\011int bl=b.length();\012\011for(int i=0;i<=bl;i++){\012\011\011char c=b.c_str()[i];\012\011\011if (c>=48&&c<=57){\012\011\011\011pudelka[lamount].rozmiar*=10;\012\011\011\011pudelka[lamount].rozmiar+=(int)c-48;\012\011\011\011pudelka[lamount].zajente=false;\012\011\011} else {\012\011\011\011if(!(pudelka[lamount].rozmiar>=1&&pudelka[lamount].rozmiar<=1000000000)) die("Liczba mo\277e wynosi\346 od 1 do 1000000000(10^9)");\012\011\011\011lamount++;\012\011\011\011if(lamount>=a) break;\012\011\011}\012\011}\012\011int cpa=lamount;\012\011int e=0;\012\011while (true){\012\011\011for(int z=e;z<=cpa;z++)\012\011\011\011if(pudelka[z].rozmiar>pudelka[e].rozmiar&&!pudelka[z].zajente){\012\011\011\011\011pudelka[z].zajente=true;\012\011\011\011\011lamount--; break;\012\011\011\011}\012\011\011if(e>=cpa){ cout << "" << lamount+1; break; }\012\011\011e++;\012\011\011}\012\011exit(0);\012\011return(0);\012}\012
```

what i tried to remove \012 and \011 was

```
 $this->data['StoredFile']['data'] = str_replace("\012","\n",$this->data['StoredFile']['data']);
 $this->data['StoredFile']['data'] = str_replace("\011","\t",$this->data['StoredFile']['data']);
```

Also used

```
$this->data['StoredFile']['data'] = stripslashes($this->data['StoredFile']['data']);
```

wchich removed \0 and then by str_replace i removed 11 and 12... but i noticed that for e.x. int i = 12;  was changed to int i = \n; what i dont wont to happen ;<

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert ASCII TO UTF-8 Encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983989/convert-ascii-to-utf-8-encoding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [str_ireplace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php).

```
$output = str_ireplace (array('\012','\011'),array("\n","\t"), $string);
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/rqbI5NNg).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `chr` function to replace ascii characters with whatever char/string you need or want:

```
str_replace(array(chr(012), chr(011)), array("\n","\t"), $string);
```

AFAIK, that should do the trick, and should avoid your replacing anything by accident. 
See [the docs here](http://php.net/chr).

That being said, there might be more ascii chars in your input string, so perhaps the `iconv` function is a better fit:

```
echo iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $string);
```

[The docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php). 
Another link, to another question SO, [perhaps worth a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983989/convert-ascii-to-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: The accepted answer failed for me, and the method in your first example worked. Thank you.