# How to convert ascii / 7bit email to utf8?

Tags: php, email, utf-8, ascii, imap

I read e-mails via php imap, and I can convert the header data to utf8.

But some email body is in ascii / 7bit, and I can't convert it.

No change by `iconv($row['encode'],'utf-8' ,$row['text']);` or `mb_convert_encoding($row['text'], $row['encode'], "UTF-8");` and `imap_utf8($row['text']);` fails.

Do you have any idea to get off the `3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D` and others from the mail body?

Comment: What others? I believe `3D` is actually hex, for the ascii character `=`

Comment: `=C3=ADt=C3=A9 =C3=A9 =C3=B6rt=C3=A9nt, mi=C3=B3ta utolj=C3=A1ra` is there any decoding method to change these `=C3=B6` to understandabe letters?

Comment: That's UTF-8 encoded as quoted-printable.  Any half-decent MIME library should handle these transparently for you.

Comment: Other posibility to convert encodings [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33744256/4558483).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [quoted_printable_decode](http://php.net/quoted_printable_decode), that should help.

Comment: That's still what you are going to need.  You are probably invoking it incorrectly.  You pass it the MIME part which is quoted-printable encoded, not the entire message.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "fails"? Are you getting errors or unecpected results (pls. Update Q with latest code and show output...€