# Strings differents but equals in php

Tags: php, vtiger

I am using eclipse editor. I am programming within vtiger 5.4. in my file config.inc.php the variable $default_charset is setted as

```
$default_charset = 'UTF-8';
```

I'm trying to make a sql query in mysql using the next variable

```
$sql = "select cod_dpto from vtiger_ubi where dpto='" . $dpto . "'";
```

When I print the variable `$dpto` I get `"SAÑA"`, but the execution of the query mysql

```
$adb->query ( $sql );
```

doesn't work. But when I modify my query as:

```
$sql = "select cod_dpto from vtiger_ubi where dpto='SAÑA'";
```

the instruction

```
$adb->query ( $sql );
```

returns the values that I need.

Could you help me please, how can I convert my variable `$dpto` such that the sql query works well.

**EDIT**

I trying to make the query with the below code, without vtiger, and I get 0 results for thw two cases with variable and writing 'SAÑA'

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "peru2006";
$dbname = "consuladoperurio_com_br_2";
$port = "3306";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli ( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $port );
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die ( "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
}
$sql = "select cod_dpto from vtiger_ubigeo where dpto='$dpto'";
echo $sql;
$result = $conn->query ( $sql );
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
    echo "id: " . $row ["cod_dpto"] "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close ();
```

Comment: Where is the data in variable `$dpto` coming from? POST? Database?

Comment: What does `mb_detect_encoding($dpto);` return?

Comment: @Juan try `utf8_encode($dpto)` before inserting it into the query.

Comment: @Juan `iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $dpto);` appears to be a better option I just found out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983989/convert-ascii-to-utf-8-encoding

Comment: @ajmedway $dpto is filled with a query.

Comment: @Juan what is the collation/encoding of the database table?

Comment: @pbond I had tested that, that doesn't work.

Comment: @Juan probaly $dpto got from database, and it will fail on next query because actual value of $dpto is not unicode (maybe cause is by your database configuaration). The solution is you must check the data which $dpto got from and tell us.

Comment: `if (!$adb->query($sql)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $adb->error);
}` run this and tell us the error

Comment: @ajmedway I run that but I don't get any error. but when I execute, after, $adb->fetch_array ( $adb->query($sql) ); I don't get any data.

Comment: @Juan, right so no error, fine. Please check your database collation and check the specific table collation/encoding and let us know

Comment: @ajmedway table collation utf8_general_ci

Comment: @Juan that should be fine... please update the question with the code that builds the `$dpto` var including the MySQL select statement

Comment: @ajmedway I had edited my question.

Comment: @Juan until you show the code of where the data in variable `$dpto` is coming from, I cannot help any further

Comment: @Juan i.e. where `$dpto = x` occurs, and showing where x comes from

Answer (score -1):

Your Select statement looks like this:

```
$sql = "select cod_dpto from vtiger_ubi where dpto='".SAÑA."';
```

you'll probably want it to look like:

```
$sql = "select cod_dpto from vtiger_ubi where dpto='$dpto'";
```

Notice no concat operator, and the variable is only wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: He properly escapes the variable, your first line isn't how it's actually parsed.

Comment: @Kisaragi thanks, but I tested that, and that doesnot work

Comment: @pbond is right, that's not how it works when using a php string literal, it will be parsed like so: dpto='SAÑA'

Comment: @Juan I was just pointing out that pbond is correct, the top line is not how it really works